# how to use user schema inside items schema in mongoose to verify admin authority

Tags: express, mongoose

i am trying to build an ecommerce to sell different items, i am trying to authorise admin only to create the items data base so i used the below function to create the item

```
static createItem = async(req,res)=>{
        try{
            const adminId= await userModel.find({_id:req.user._id})._id
            if(req.user.username==adminId){
            const newItem = new itemModel({...req.body})
            newItem.save()
            res.send({apistatus:true, message:"Item created" , data:newItem})
            }
            else{throw new Error("user has no authority to create items")}
        }
        catch(e){res.send({apistatus:false, data:e.message})}
    }
```

the code gets the admin user right but did not give any of its properties to use them in comparison to verify that i have authenticated admin login

Answer (score 0):

---

You need to remove `._id` after doing find!

```js
const adminUser = await userModel.find({_id:req.user._id})
```

Hope it helps!